# jquery mobile changePage() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating a webapp using phonegap and jquerymobile. When i am using changePage to go to other page then it is not working.Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function clickEvent()
{
    $.mobile.changePage("account_page.html", null, true, true);
}
</script>
<body>
<div style="top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
    <img src="images/login_screen.JPG" alt="login_screen" width="320"    onclick="clickEvent()"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i use

```
window.location.href = 'file:///android_asset/www/account_page.html';
```

Then it is working...Why is it so?

Comment: It works, may be try $.mobile.changePage("account_page.html") only...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$.mobile.changePage doesnt load another html into view. it scans the html in the html whose link u gave, gets the first jqm 'page' on it and adds that into the dom(not the entire html)
 If this is not what you intended to do and wanted to load the full account_page.html into the dom then u'll have to use either

```
window.location.href or navigator.app.loadUrl
```