# How to debug $.mobile.changePage?

Tags: qt, debugging, jquery-mobile

My page is not changing when calling `$.mobile.changePage`. An error message appears but that's all!

How can I monitor the error? Is there a status code or a response message? Is there any alternative to `$.mobile.changePage` in JQuery Mobile?

My code is as simple as possible:

```
$.mobile.changePage("page.html", {showLoadMsg: true});
```

For information, this code is embedded in a QWebKit and I don't use a server. This is only standalone HTML. Standard asynchronous requests work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [QWebInspector](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebinspector.html) to inspect the response of the ajax call

Comment: Well yes but how to install FireBug in a QWebKit window?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9362457/902025).

I should have used `window.location.href = "page.html";` instead!